Верно ли оформлено предложение с цитатами?
Иногда люди, страдающие от бессонницы, формируют различные убеждения, препятствующие сну, например: «у меня так и не получится заснуть» или «опять завтра буду никаким из-за этой бессонницы» или «не могу нормально спать без бокала вина».
Конкретно здесь меня интересует, верно ли оформлено перечисление цитат (+нужны ли запятые после "или").

Правильно:
Иногда люди, страдающие от бессонницы, формируют различные убеждения, препятствующие сну, например: «у меня так и не получится заснуть», или «опять завтра буду никаким из-за этой бессонницы», или «не могу нормально спать без бокала вина».
Пояснение
В данном предложении используется конструкция с обобщающим словом "убеждения" и однородным рядом.
Знаки препинания в однородном ряду ставятся согласно правилу Розенталя для повторяющегося союза ИЛИ (здесь он повторяется дважды).
6. Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз 
повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то запятая 
ставится между всеми однородными членами: Листья в поле 
пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят; Лён, и полотна, и пряжу 
несут; А вокруг были дым, и бой, и смерть (М. Г.); 
Отрывистый и ломаный звук метался, и прыгал, и бежал куда-то 
в сторону от других (Андр.); Иные хозяева вырастили уже 
вишни, или сирень, или жасмин (Ф); Только мальвы, да 
ноготки, да кручёный паныч цвели кое-где по дворам (Пан.); 
Весь вечер Ленский был рассеян, то молчалив, то весел вновь. 

